# What service should I use so that I can alias email such that x@example.tld would be forwarded to accountname+x@gmail.com?

Tags: email

I currently have a domain registered at Google Domains which is <firstname><lastname>.us and I'm wondering if there's any way for me to have all email of the type <x>@<firstname><lastname>.us be redirected to my Gmail account <firstname>.<lastname>+<x>@gmail.com. Google support has already told me that they can't do this using Google Domains so I'm asking if there are any other services (either mail services or otherwise) that can. I am willing to move my domain or pay for a separate service if necessary.

After reading my question I've noticed that there could be some confusion, I would like this to be run automatically.  Technically, I *can* create up to 100 manual aliases of the form x@example.com to redirect to exampleaccountname+x@gmail.com but, that would require that I create the alias before using the custom email address.